# **kwds not working in pybliometrics.scopus.ScopusSearch

Tags: python, scopus, pybliometrics

I am currently using pybliometrics.scopus.ScopusSearch to get all results to a search. I want to constrain my search to a specific date range. However, the date kwds is not working.

My code currently looks like

```
q = "TITLE(ecotourism) AND TITLE-ABS-KEY(quant*)"
scopus_search = ScopusSearch(q, date='2002-2007')
```

However, this is returning documents that are also outside of the specified dates. It is actually returning all the files for the query, disregarding the published dates. I do not want to include the dates in the query, as there is a maximum of 8 connectors in Scopus and other queries I have are going to be much more compplex than this example.

Any help is appreciated!

Comment: Please edit the question to limit it to a specific problem with enough detail to identify an adequate answer.

Comment: Daer @Community, the answer is in perfect shape

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The kwds arguments work, but they are irrelevant when you re-use cached results. You probably ran the query without the kwds first, didn't you? When you refresh this query, the kwds will apply again.

Compare this:

```
import pandas as pd
from pybliometrics.scopus import ScopusSearch

q = "TITLE(ecotourism) AND TITLE-ABS-KEY(quant*)"

scopus_search = ScopusSearch(q, date='2002-2007')
df = pd.DataFrame(scopus_search.results)
df["year"] = df["coverDate"].str[:4].astype(int)
print(df["year"].max())
# 2007

scopus_search = ScopusSearch(q)
df = pd.DataFrame(scopus_search.results)
df["year"] = df["coverDate"].str[:4].astype(int)
print(df["year"].max())
# 2007

scopus_search = ScopusSearch(q, refresh=True)
df = pd.DataFrame(scopus_search.results)
df["year"] = df["coverDate"].str[:4].astype(int)
print(df["year"].max())
# 2024

scopus_search = ScopusSearch(q, date='2002-2007')
df = pd.DataFrame(scopus_search.results)
df["year"] = df["coverDate"].str[:4].astype(int)
print(df["year"].max())
# 2024

scopus_search = ScopusSearch(q, date='2002-2007', refresh=True)
df = pd.DataFrame(scopus_search.results)
df["year"] = df["coverDate"].str[:4].astype(int)
print(df["year"].max())
# 2007
```